# CV-PLS old requests room moderator/CM authorization

Tags: support, chat, moderators

Around a month ago, I created [a new chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253110/cv-pls-old-questions) intended for registering questions which should be closed, but don't have recent activity within the scope set by [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Any room with a collection of close-worthy questions will lead to readers voting on them; as such, I decided to make a formal room for [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) for old questions. The room has gained interest from a few regulars of SOCVR, and has been a modest success so far.

Not long after the creation of this room, some concerns were raised and pointed out, the most pressing of these being that rooms whose purpose is moderation of SO need to be known by and authorized by the moderators or CMs of SO. This post seeks to address this concern.

**All the [rules of SOCVR](https://socvr.org/faq) apply**, except the requirement for recent activity. Only [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) is permitted. All other requests belong in SOCVR. This is a specialized room whose only purpose is [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) for inactive questions. As such, the room functions similarly to SOCVR, but with **no overlap in target moderation**. It's not a duplicate or competition to SOCVR; rather, it's a supplement. No responsibilities are to be duplicated.

There's currently 2 room owners; me and [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee). We are both very active in various chat rooms.

All requests are archived: [completed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253305/cv-pls-oq-requests-graveyard); [cancelled](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253387/cv-pls-oq-dev-null).

A rough count currently shows 106 closed questions, and 7 cancelled requests, including 4 incorrect request types (userscript issue in at least 2 cases) The other requests were cancelled after issues raised by others. 4 requests (3 completed, 1 cancelled) were moved to the general trash room, because the archival rooms didn't exist yet.

Mostly severely off-topic questions (not about programming) have been closed so far.

The room also serves as a registry/archive of questions that should be closed, but have not yet been so. If a request is left unhandled, it remains in the registry. Bad requests and disputed ones are moved to the archive of cancelled requests. Because these questions have no recent activity, archiving valid and correct requests for future closing is not an issue in terms of potential edits salvaging them, which may be an issue with questions which do have recent activity. If an old question changes in such a way that it should no longer be closed, requests are moved to the archive of cancelled requests, upon a notice of this.

##### Is this room necessary?

Many of the same arguments for SOCVR apply. The room is not a solution in search for a problem, but a solution for the problems with the existing queues. It's frustrating to flag and vote to close questions over and over again, only for these flags and votes to age out. This is a personal experience of both the room owners, and I assume others. If we could successfully curate the site with the existing tools, this room would not have emerged in the first place.

[Quoting tripleee](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56222844#56222844):

> I close vote [these same old posts] approx once a month in the vain hope that one day someone will come across them in the close vote queue and concur

Had the queues worked, we would not need this room. The reality is that the queues don't work; having flags and votes age out is work wasted and thrown away. It's demotivating. Not only is this room an effective solution to this problem; it is also much better at handling disputes/questions/discussions. There may be additional concerns with closing older content. The queues cannot handle this. Meta will still continue to be the location for discussing less clear, or wider, cases. There's no intention to take away Meta's broader moderation rights.

An alternative to this room is to remove the requirement for [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) requests to only concern questions with recent activity, in SOCVR. If that happens, this room serves no purpose, and the only reasonable decision is to shut it down, or put it on hold. However, I think it’s important not to lower SOCVR’s requirement for recent activity. There are a lot of recent questions to handle, and as [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) is the most common request made in SOCVR, it's important to ensure that SOCVR remains focused on handling the content of immediate necessity. There's only a limited number of close votes available for each user per day, and it makes sense to prioritize these on immediate matters first. Cleaning up older content is a secondary task to many curators. So I don’t believe that the right course of action is to loosen that rule in SOCVR. This filtering ensures that close votes are prioritized correctly. It also [ensures that SOCVR remains effective](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56281685#56281685) at its mission. This is important for handling content with recent activity, and that's what members of SOCVR expect.

The room was early on added to [Sloshy](https://github.com/tripleee/sloshy), an anti-freezing bot, simply because I didn’t expect the room to always be gaining requests, and that’s fine. It’s not an explicit goal to search for old questions to close them; rather, it’s a location to post old questions that should be closed, when you come across them. Simply put, the room is not an encouragement in itself. Participation is not sought, but welcomed. The experience so far has been that the room does in fact not require an anti-freezing bot, as there's usually a few requests posted every day. The archival rooms have also been added to Sloshy, which especially for the cancelled requests, may show up to be necessary.

Whether or not there's a need to search for and close old questions is rather irrelevant. This room should not be a priority for members, however, they may choose to participate based on their own preferences. Cleaning up old and inactive content is a valid curation task on the site, and letting us do this more efficiently shouldn't be a problem.

In the end, I think the most important measure is that the participants find it to be meaningful. Curating the site is our way of contributing and helping; this room is simply one of the tools we can use for this task, which we enjoy doing. We find motivation in keeping the standards and quality of the site up; closing close-worthy content, even old stuff, is one means of doing so.

##### Is this room counter-productive?

Not to the ones of us that participate in it. It’s opt-in; we’re not asking Meta for cleanup efforts, of any kind, or being disruptive in any other way. This is an autonomous cleanup effort; an aid to our already existing every-day curation. But should we close old questions? Yes. Age is irrelevant. The close reasons apply to all questions, irrespective of their age.

Some may say that it's pointless to close old garbage that nobody sees. But if nobody sees the garbage anyway, it doesn’t hurt to close and delete it, does it?

Closing questions also make them eligible for deletion, which allows us to remove content that simply doesn't belong on the site. Questions with should be closed, but have historical value, can be locked, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058496/moving-from-c-to-c), which was closed a few days ago.

By quickly handling requests, there’s a possibility of not letting the questions linger in the review queue, which potentially reduces the load on the queue reviewers. I have no data to back this up. Do note that this would nonetheless be secondary.

##### Posting [reopen-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-pls)

It's reasonable to make the same people closing a question responsible for reopening them. Currently, 100% of everyone participating in this room, including the room owners, are regulars in SOCVR. The current rule is that [reopen-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-pls) requests are posted in SOCVR. We have no intention of moving any responsibilities from SOCVR; SOCVR is already handling all these requests very well. SOCVR is faster, and a better room for handling [reopen-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-pls). This is also within their mandate. This follows the policy that everything which is appropriate in SOCVR is to be posted in there, and not in this room.

##### Room abuse

We are not looking to close everything on the site. The room is not an attempt at closing valid questions, or circumventing the safeguards in place by the queues; any such intentional usage is abuse of the room. The room is a continuation of the already existing curation efforts on the site.

The success so far does show that this room has merit, and does follow the rules of SO. Abuse will be dealt with. Disputes have arisen about closing certain questions. These disputes were either settled, or the requests were cancelled. This is good, and is also something the queues fail at; discussions about the questions targeted for closing are welcome.

Any abuse which is beyond the room owners' abilities to handle will naturally be escalated to moderators. Because of the room's narrow scope, and small surface of moderation, the potential for abuse, and for abuse to go unnoticed, is smaller than for many other curation rooms. Because the room's primary purpose is curation, room owners and regulars are familiar with curation, moderation, and handling of various cases.

Finally; we're all friendly people. :) Mistakes do happen, and the right course of action will always be to correct them, and learn from them.

##### Message to moderators/CMs

We wish to continue the curation efforts through the usage of this room. The request as such is for the moderators' support/authorization for the existence of this room. We understand that you may be skeptic about it, however, we're ready to continue showing that this room has its positive value. The room already has support from seasoned curators. May we be entrusted with the support from moderators too?

Comment: Coming from an active curator and a SOCVR regular (more of a passive one, but still), ya'll have my support - godspeed. If the room manages to uphold the general SOCVR rules, I don't see any significant downsides to have a more specialized room for exclusively dealing with old questions running afoul of the activity rule.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am an SOCVR Room Owner and moderator. Mostly speaking for myself here.

I... don't think you explicitly need moderator or CM permission to do this (CMs don't generally approve stuff like this anyways, leaving it to moderators). If you want to close/reopen things, go ahead. We're not going to stop you for just doing that. We've not stopped other non-SOCVR efforts either.

So why does SOCVR have all those rules? Mostly because you can get into all sorts of community trouble if you're not careful. Imagine your room starts closing a lot of things by the same user. You think that user wouldn't notice and start flagging things? At that point, it becomes a moderator problem. Were the actions proper? Is there any actual user targeting here? And at that point moderators start looking at your room...

The SOCVR rules are mainly there to prevent that. Some people have tried "SOCVR without all those pesky rules" and found that it's much harder than it looks. You'll attract people who have ulterior motives that will get you put under a microscope and possibly get you shut down if/when you make too many problems. It sounds like you intend to keep the SOCVR rules (which have been crafted over many years to avoid that problem), so I doubt there will be a problem here.

As a Room Owner, the main thing about the "old posts" rule is that we don't want to close *all the things*. There's a ton of old stuff that doesn't fit the modern ruleset anymore, and we could easily eat up every available CV in the room on just old things. Thus we prefer anything with recent activity. There's no community rule there, just a room preference. If you want to have "SOCVR without age restrictions", feel free.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very useful and transparent response. I personally had the same idea that you have, of what’s required, when I created the room. I didn’t expect having to ask for permission. At the same time, several users suggested that this is needed, and another moderator complained about a lack of moderator support for another room for moderation purposes, in the past. I managed to find that room, and read through the entire transcript. I decided it would be better to be a bit ahead of things, than to wait for possible negative reactions.

Comment: Simply put, my response was that most of the concerns raised were unreasonable. I figured it would be better to address them than to ignore them, though.

Answer (score 4):

My concern is... if the purpose of SOCVR's requirement is to ensure questions that need to be actioned aren't drowned out by older less important question closures, and the users of the new room are all also SOCVR users... doesn't this room completely circumvent the purpose of that rule in SOCVR, assuming users are actually using all of their votes in a given day?

In practice, I'd expect it not to... and wonder if the SOCVR rule is even necessary.

Comment: Users don't always spend their daily closure vote quota in SOCVR. SOCVR cannot adapt its requirements based on a daily difference in traffic. I do think closure votes should be prioritized in SOCVR first; this is also what [tripleee pointed out](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56218075#56218075).

Comment: If we would come to a point where too many requests are posted in the room, compared to how many can be acted upon, the room functions as an archive of unclosed closable questions. This may also be mitigated by a userscript which ranks the requests based on the number of close votes on each question. This is however a concern which is not immediate. It’s better to revisit this outside of this post.

Comment: *assuming users are actually using all of their votes in a given day* - there are certainly users who actually use all their close votes, but I'm not one of them. I'm a regular user in SOCVR, but I don't spend my whole day there. Sometimes I only find time to pop in 1 or 2 times during a day and cast a few votes and simply don't find 50 requests to vote on. Then I can also see if there's some old stuff to vote on in this new room and at the end of the day I'm still far away from spending my 50 votes.

Comment: "This may also be mitigated by a userscript which ranks the requests based on the number of close votes on each question." - that doesn't seem very useful; the only ordinary values would be 1 and 2 (since 3 votes would actually close the question, and the person making the request should have cast one).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If there's a lot of requests in the room (let's say 100), and voters only  have a few votes to cast, and the frequency of people voting, is very small, it is useful, or else the votes will be scattered across the questions, and eventually age out. This ranking would be to prevent the close votes from aging out.

Comment: I understand the goal. I'm saying that I think you will need something more sophisticated in order to achieve it.